# why are all my keybindings only apply to one object when I clearly assigned some keybindings to the other object?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

So I created two objects from tank1 class, and their names are tank1 and tank2. I want tank1 to shift right with RIGHT key and to shift left with LEFT key, and tank2 to shift right with D and to shift left with A key. But when I finished compiling my code, the tank2 shift left with A, and LEFT keys, and shift right with D, and RIGHT keys, and tank1 doesn't shift with any key at all. Is there any way to fix this so tank 1 shift with LEFT, RIGHT key?

here is my gridbasegame class:

```
public class GridBasedGameDriver {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("my world");
    private JPanel panel;
    private List<Drawable> drawables= new ArrayList();
    private Terrain terrain;
    private Tank1 Tank1;
    private Tank1 Tank2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GridBasedGameDriver().start();
    }



    private void start() { // REPAINT 
        setUpGame();

        frame.setBackground(new Color(127, 127, 127));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel() { public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); drawGame(g); } }; // what does paint componet and draw game do, 
        //and where does the 
        //super come from?
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600)); // doesn't matter, can be set again manually
        frame.add(panel); // so frame needs to add panel
        frame.pack(); // no idea, probably not important
        // int b= (int)(Math.random()*100+100); //100-199, only here for fun doesn't change a damn thing





        panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"),"slideRight");
        panel.getActionMap().put("slideRight",new AbstractAction(){ 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Tank1.moveRight();
                panel.repaint();
            } 
            });
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();


        panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"),"slideLeft");
        panel.getActionMap().put("slideLeft",new AbstractAction(){ 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Tank1.moveleft();
                panel.repaint();
            } 
            });
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();


        panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"),"slideRight");
        panel.getActionMap().put("slideRight",new AbstractAction(){ 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Tank2.moveRight();
                panel.repaint();
            } 
            });
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();       


        panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"),"slideLeft");
        panel.getActionMap().put("slideLeft",new AbstractAction(){ 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Tank2.moveleft();
                panel.repaint();
            } 
            });
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();



        setUpObjects();
        frame.repaint();
    }


    private void setUpObjects() {
        terrain = new Terrain(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()); // where does the panel come from? 
        terrain.initialize();
        List<Integer> b=terrain.getlist();
        Tank1 = new Tank1(20,0,b);
        Tank2 = new Tank1(740,1,b);

        drawables.add(terrain); // I get it, so the terrain has drawable, and once it gets added to drawable array it implements its own drawable

        drawables.add(Tank1);
        drawables.add(Tank2);

    }

    public void drawGame(Graphics g) {
        for(Drawable dr:drawables) {
            dr.draw(g);
        }

    }
```

and here is my tank1 class:

```
public class Tank1 implements Drawable {
    public int gi; 
    public int it;
    public List<Integer> b;
    List<Integer> Krell = new ArrayList<>();
    public Tank1(int gi, int it, List<Integer> b) {
        this.b=b;
        this.gi=gi;
        this.it=it;
    }

    public void moveleft() {
        gi=gi-1;
    }
    public void moveRight() {
        gi=gi+1;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method student
        if (it==0) {        
        g.setColor(new Color(230,50,58)); // draws that recoatlve
        }
        if(it==1) {
        g.setColor(new Color(120,160,60)); // draws that recoatlve  
        }
            g.fillRect(gi, b.get(gi)-25, 25, 25); //draws that rectangle

    }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might first thought is, `JPanel` is not focusable by default, so requesting focus in the window won't do anything.  Besides, the point of using key bindings like this is to avoid having to deal with "grab focus" style hacks.

There are a couple of variations to `getInputMap`, one which allows you to define the focus context in which the bindings will be triggered.  You might consider using `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, for example...

```
panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"),"slideRight");
```